# Solving the cost function optimization problem using linear programming

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

My cost function is in the form $$ \Delta u^T P \Delta u + q^T \Delta u$$How shall I put it in the form of $c^T x$ to be able to solve it using linear programming?

Comment: What do the different factors represent?

Comment: I am assuming $\Delta u$ is the variable, in which case the answer is: you can't. It's not linear, so you can't represent it with linear programming. It is, however, a quadratic function; if $P$ is positive definite, it's a convex QP, and there are plenty of codes to solve those (including most codes for LP). (I'm also assuming you have constraints you're not sharing with us here.)

Answer (score 0):

Assume $P$ symmetric positive definit. Then your problem is equivalent to 
$$
\min 0
$$
subject to
$$
P\Delta u + q = 0.
$$